# Laravel custom permalink

Tags: php, laravel, url, permalinks, slug

I am trying to change the url of my article page so instead of showing the article id I'd like to show the article title.

Currently the URL is as follows;
`https://www.example.com/posts/post/32`
Where 32 is just a random article id.

Instead I like it to display as follows;
`https://www.example.com/posts/post/my-amazing-article`

Now I have looked in the laravel documentation and different posts on stackoverflow and tried a bunch of stuff but I'm obviously making a mistake somewhere cus nothing seems to work so im pretty much back where I started.

Blade

```
<a href="{{ route('post', $a->id) }}" class="feature-box-01 media" id="smallbox"></a>
```

Route

```
Route::get('/posts/post/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\WelcomeController::class, 'post'])->name('post');
```

Controller

```
public function post(request $request){
    $id = $request->id;
    $article = Tinymce::find($id);

    return view('/post')->with('articles, $articles');
}
```

Now the articles, which are saved in Tinymce, are actually created on a different controller on subdomain.

```
public function tinymce(Request $request)
    {
        
        if(request()->ajax())
        {   
            if($request->article_id == null)
            {
                $tinymce = new Tinymce;
                
                
            }else{

                $tinymce = Tinymce::find($request->article_id);
            }
            
            $tinymce->description = $request->description;
            $tinymce->content = $request->myContent;
            $tinymce->title = $request->title;
            $tinymce->author = $request->author;
            $tinymce->publish = $request->publish;
            $title = $tinymce->title;
            $slug = Str::slug($title, "-");
            $tinymce->slug = $slug;            
            $tinymce->save();

            
            return $tinymce->id;
        }
        
    }
```

As you can see I've turned the title into a slug as I read somewhere that's the way to go to use custom url but I didn't get very far with it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Make your life easier and use an existing package for this. https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sluggable or https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable are both great.

Comment: or just not use a convoluted package for every little thing of your application, and use the `Str::slug` helper which is included in Laravel and you're already using

Comment: also you probably save yourself a lot of issues if you name your parameters and functons properly. That `{id}` in your url is no longer a numerical id, it is a slug. So change it to `{slug}` and use the `$tinymce->slug` property when you need it. Your controller is named `WelcomeController` which you probably want to call `PostController` or `TinymceController`. Your controller functions could then become `show` and `store` and immediately become much more readable.

Comment: @Flame There's a lot of edge cases around slugging that the packages handle, that I find quite valuable. Redirecting old slugs when they change, scoped handling of unique slugs, etc. Every time I've done DIY slugging I wind up in a situation where I realize the packages have handled scenarios I don't want to slog through implementing.

Comment: "Redirecting old slugs when they change" there doesnt seem to be any functionality like that in `spatie/laravel-sluggable`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Explanation:***

First, As you said you stored slug into your database. so, that's good.

From `Controller` to `View`, you can get that `slug` into `post` object.

Blade View : (you have to pass `slug` in route url)

```
<a href="{{ route('post', $a->slug) }}" class="feature-box-01 media" id="smallbox"></a>
```

Route : (make `id` to `slug`)

```
Route::get('/posts/post/{slug}', [App\Http\Controllers\WelcomeController::class, 'post'])->name('post');
```

Controller : (now you can get `slug` from the second parameter)

```
public function post(request $request, $slug = ''){
    $article = Tinymce::where('slug', $slug)->first();

    return view('/post', compact('article'));
}
```

Now, you can use access custom URLs using slug.

I Hope, it helps you. @assiemp